# C# MYSQL - Search filtering a datagridview with a combobox and textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, combobox, textbox

Hi I'm trying to search filter a `datagridview` by using a `combobox` and `textbox`.

I have successfully done so but it only works properly when I search for the ID column. Other columns just crash display the following message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Name LIKE 'd%'' at line 1

The **d** letter in that error message is just the letter I was trying to filter the search with.

Could somebody please help me solve this issue?

My code is below

```
string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;";
MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
try
        {
            if (comboBoxSrchPatient.Text == "ID")
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from clinic_inventory_system.patient WHERE ID LIKE '" + txtSearchPatient.Text + "%'", conDatabase);
                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                dataPatientGridView.DataSource = dbdataset;
            }
            else if (comboBoxSrchPatient.Text == "FIRST NAME")
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from clinic_inventory_system.patient WHERE First Name LIKE '" + txtSearchPatient.Text + "%'", conDatabase);
                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                dataPatientGridView.DataSource = dbdataset;
            }

            else if (comboBoxSrchPatient.Text == "LAST NAME")
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from clinic_inventory_system.patient WHERE Last Name LIKE '" + txtSearchPatient.Text + "%'", conDatabase);
                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                dataPatientGridView.DataSource = dbdataset;
            }

            else if (comboBoxSrchPatient.Text == "AGE")
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from clinic_inventory_system.patient WHERE Age LIKE '" + txtSearchPatient.Text + "%'", conDatabase);
                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                dataPatientGridView.DataSource = dbdataset;
            }

            else if (comboBoxSrchPatient.Text == "CONTACT NUMBER")
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from clinic_inventory_system.patient WHERE Contact Number LIKE '" + txtSearchPatient.Text + "%'", conDatabase);
                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                dataPatientGridView.DataSource = dbdataset;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your field names contains spaces.
To use them in a query your need to enclose them between backticks (ALT+096)

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"select * from 
    clinic_inventory_system.patient WHERE `Last Name` LIKE ....";
```

Said that, consider, as soon as possible, to change your queries to use a parameterized query

```
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"select * from 
            clinic_inventory_system.patient 
            WHERE `First Name` LIKE @name", conDatabase);
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSearchPatient.Text + "%";
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dbdataset);
    dataPatientGridView.DataSource = dbdataset;
}
```

In this way your code is safer because it is no more possible to build an Sql Injection attack against your db and, if  the `First Name` contains a single quote, you don't have a syntax error again

Comment: Ah I see. It works now and I will now fix up my queries by parameterizing them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, with First Name, Last Name and Contact Number, you need to escape the columns correctly.
Since you're using MariaDB, you should use backticks (`) to escape the column names.

Secondly, your Age query fails because you can't perform a LIKE on a numeric column. You should use = (equals).

Hope that helps.

Also, considering switching to prepared statements if you're using data the user has provided directly in your SQL. At the moment, you're open to SQL Injection.

Comment: Understood. I will fix all of that right now. Thank you for the reply and heads up.

Answer (score 0):

you should listen to Huw Jones.

you dont want to get audited by a security firm and have sql injection problems. Parameterized your query is mySql supports it.